# Remove data attribute from html with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover

I work in a bootstrap navbar and I want to remove a data-hover from the page using jQuery only if the page is displayed on a touch screen device.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="navbar-fixed">
 <div class="container navbar-no-horizzontal-padding">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-fixed-collapse">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/loghi/logoConScritta.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo U.G.B." /></a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-no-horizzontal-padding" id="navbar-fixed-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn">
      <li><a class="menu-item home" href="./index.php">Homepage</a></li>
      <hr class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" />
      <!--<li class="hidden-xs"><a class="menu-separetor"><hr></a></li>-->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="menu-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Società <b class="caret hidden-xs"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" role="menu">
          <li><a href="storia-unione-giovane-biella.php">Storia</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="atleti-unione-giovane-biella.php">Atleti</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Allenatori</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Dirigenti</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="record-unione-giovane-biella.php">Record sociali</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <hr class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" />
      <!--<li class="hidden-xs"><a class="menu-separetor"><hr></a></li>-->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="menu-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Galleria <b class="caret hidden-xs"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" role="menu">
          <li><a href="galleria-unione-giovane-biella.php">Foto</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Video</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <hr class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" />
      <!--<li class="hidden-xs"><a class="menu-separetor"><hr></a></li>-->
      <li><a class="menu-item" href="">News</a></li>
      <hr class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" />
      <!--<li class="hidden-xs"><a class="menu-separetor"><hr></a></li>-->
      <li><a class="menu-item contatti" href="contatti-unione-giovane-biella.php">Contatti</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

I use this data to create a dropdown-hover effect, but when the screen is touch  I want to remove this effect and add a new effect. Theoretically if I remove the data-hover the script shouldn't be performed, but the problem is that also when I remove this data the effect performed is the same of the hover effect as if the data attributes weren't delete

I try to use this function but nothing happen

```
if (is_touch_device())
    $('.navbar .navbar-nav').removeData("hover");

if (is_touch_device())
    $('.navbar .navbar-nav').data("hover", null);
```

With this instead I delete/edit the attribute from the DOM but the result is the same

```
if (is_touch_device())
    $('.navbar .navbar-nav').removeAttr("data-hover");

if (is_touch_device())
    $('.navbar .navbar-nav').attr("data-hover", "");
```

I don't understand why also when the DOM is edit the effect is performed as if nothing had been changed

Comment: Are you sure the code is running? Are you sure `is_touch_device()` is returning `true`? Lastly - "not work" and "nothing happen" aren't useful problem statements. If you're trying to remove the attr so that bootstrap won't use it, there's a real chance that you're too late, and bootstrap has "hooked" into before your code runs / changes anything.

Comment: Are you using some kind of component to render the dropdown? What is it? Can you please share, so I can see the docs? Thanks

Comment: look this. its working fine. no data-hover. http://jsbin.com/bixuhupequ/2/edit?html,js,output , maybe the problem is with your is_touch_device

Comment: Yes @cale_b, I'm sure that the code run and the is_touch_device() return true. I use this function in other case and it works properly. If the problem is that the bootstarp has "hooked", there is a way to "unhook"?

Comment: @pedromartins For the bootstrap dropdown hover I use this [effect](https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/#dropdowns-installing). The problem is that in large touch screen, like tablet (not phone), I think there is a bug. Indeed, sometimes to open a dropdown menu I must click 2 times instead 1. This is the reason why I want change the effect in this devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap binded the button when the page was loaded with the parameters you set. So even if you remove them it's too late. According to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#methods), to remove the hover comportement, you have to use in v4 :

```
$('.navbar .navbar-nav').button('dispose')
```

and then reset it with the comportement you want.

in v3, the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#buttons-methods) says it's :

```
$('.navbar .navbar-nav').button('reset')
```

Comment: I try it @nico_, but unfortunately nothing change after use this function

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: I use bootstrap 3 and as I wrote above I use this [effect](https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/#dropdowns-installing) for the dropdown menu hover. The problem is that in large touch screen, like tablet (not phone), I think there is a bug. Indeed, sometimes to open a dropdown menu I must click 2 times instead 1. This is the reason why I want change the effect in this devices

Comment: Sorry then it's 'reset' and not 'dispose' (dispose is for v4), I'm updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

What if you load the script if your is_touch_device function returns false, like this?

```
if (!is_touch_device()) {
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="js/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.js"></sc' + 'ript>');
}
```

Comment: This is not a viable solution.